# Tumblr Custom Description on Tagged Pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to put up a header with description on the top of the tagged page

Example: http://splexlibrary.tumblr.com/tagged/clothing

I want a custom description under "`#clothing`" with links and text.. preferably in a new box.

But, I want this to be different in specific tags.
Example, new links and text in "`#build mode`" and so on.

*(I know this has been asked before, but hopefully its someone seeing this that knows)*

Comment: Sadly it is not possible using Tumblrs theme operators as they don't provide any filter logic. You will need to rely on client side changes.